# Anchor settings not working

Tags: vb.net

My VB.Net application is using anchoring to force certain controls to resize to their container, eg a list box on a form.  This is all pretty standard and easy to do.  However having just released the application into production I've found that on one user's computer the anchoring seems to just be ignored.  She has Windows 7, as do I.

So far example what should look like this:
[image: correct]
instead looks like this
[image: wrong]

I asked her to try a higher resolution on her screen but that didn't to help.

On one of them I was able to fix it by manually setting the width and height in form load properties of the control instead of anchoring it, but it seems a bit backward.

Comment: We'd have to know exactly how you'd set the relevant properties to know whether you've done it correctly or not.  That said, it could have something to do with the DPI of the screen.  You could try setting the `AutoSizeMode` property of the form to `Dpi` instead of `Font` to see if that is the case.

Comment: The AutoSizeMode of the forms only has options "GrowOnly" and "GrowAndShrink".  They are set to "GrowOnly" Which other properties are relevant other than the control Anchor properties?  This is happening on several forms but only on one user's computer.

Comment: Sorry, wrong property.  That should have been `AutoScaleMode`.

Comment: Ok gave that a try but didn't help.

Comment: Turned out to be a display setting on her computer - Font Size was 200%. Never come across it before. No changes required to my app which is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that the display issues were caused by user having the "Font Size" setting on her computer set to 200%. To be honest I didn't even know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the form has been resized to be too small for the anchoring to work correctly. Set the `.MinimumSize` property of the form to ensure the form does not get too small for your layout.

Older staff sometimes reduce the screen dpi to make text easier to read, which means the screen may not be big enough to display the form. To fix this, set the screen dpi back to something reasonable and increase the text size for readability.

Comment: I don't think its the minimum size - if I shrink the forms to the minimum size they work correctly, everything just shrinks proportionally.  I've been working with this application for three years and I've never seen the screens look like this.  I got the user to put her resolution up to its highest and it made no difference.

Comment: In that case check that she is running the correct version of your app. You might also want to check the `.AutoScroll` property of your form. Your second screenshot seems to have scrollbars on the form itself.

Comment: Turned out to be a display setting on her computer - Font Size was 200%. Never come across it before. No changes required to my app which is great.